How to automate operation on customers in Microsoft Partner Center Account?
I have Microsoft Partner Account where I am global admin and managing 50+ different customers. I want to automate a process where I want to read all the customers at once, fetch their users and do a certain business operation on it.
I am new to this and I want to understand how can I create a single Azure AD app which can basically connects to all the customers or if there is a way where I can get a single access token or refresh token and through that get access to every customer and get their users.
Any help or guidance please. Thanks
I created azure ad app separately for few customers and assigned application permissions to that but creating 50+ separate azure ad apps isn't a practical solution.
I also used MSAL library from Microsoft but it requires you to login via browser and take consent, after that you can access graph apis.
Since I want to automate this whole process so I need some sort of solution where I just have to kind of create a single azure ad app which connects with all customers and i can do any kind of operation in each customer without having to login, get consent everytime.
